# I don’t know if I accept my mother's conversion

Tags: rabbis, conversion-to-judaism, baal-teshuva

My parents were married before I was born and my father had my mother convert before they got married. The place of my mother's conversion was Conservative I would say and it took my mother 2 years to convert and then she went to the Mikvah. They would go to Shul most weekends, keep kosher, and light candles for Shabbat. A few years after I was born my parents got divorced and my mother quickly became non-observant and my dad slowly became less observant to the point of Reform. I grew up eating pork and not following any Jewish law. I had my bar mitzvah at the age of 14 and did read from both torah and haftorah. I remained non-observant after until the age of 15 when I went to a Reform Shul and had questions that couldn’t be answered so I went to a Conservative Shul. I went almost every Saturday for about a year and didn’t feel exactly connected yet became more and more observant. Then I went to an Orthodox Shul and felt like home and now am fully Shomar Shabbos, wrap tefillen, wash before bread etc… this addition of religion comes with added knowledge and I don’t know if my mother's conversion is accepted by Orthodox and thus if I should convert. Really weighing down on me. Am I Jewish?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Your question was closed because this site is not a good place for personal questions. Those should be asked to a rabbi well-versed in the relevant laws who will ask questions on context and personal specifics to come to a good answer. This site can't substitute for this. Maybe you can start with the rabbi of that Orthodox shul you go to? Please don't let this deter you from coming back to learn with us. Also can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?

Comment: Sometimes rabbis recommend a formal conversion "just to be sure", when there is a doubt about a person's Jewishness that they can't resolve.  In your case, that should be a simple matter.

Comment: This is really a question for your local Orthodox Beth Din

Comment: The fact of the conservative conversion is way more relevant than the subsequent loss of observance of your mother. CYLOR